# Passing instance variable from Model to View to Controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basic app. Trying to make a button that clicks and shows the next page in this case lesson.

In my controller I have:

```
def show 
  @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
end
```

In my view (show.html.erb) I have:

```
...
<p><%= link_to 'Previous', Lesson.previous(@lesson) %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'Next', Lesson.next(@lesson) %></p>
...
```

In my model I have:

```
def self.next(current_lesson)
  current_lesson.number + 1
end

def self.previous(current_lesson)
  current_lesson.number - 1
end
```

My schema includes a number column that is an integer.

However, this errors out with 'undefined method `to_model' for 0:Fixnum' and when I run @lesson in the console, it comes up as nil.

I also tried this:

```
def self.next
  current_lesson = Lesson.find(@lesson.id)
  next_lesson = current_lesson.number + 1 
end 

def self.previous 
  current_lesson = Lesson.find(@lesson.id)
  previous_lesson = current_lesson.number - 1
end
```

This however, successfully passes the model the instance variable because in the console @lesson returns the correct value but it cannot call the method.

thoughts?

Edit: another solution attempted:

I tried changing this to an instance method rather than a class method. So in the view I set @lesson.previous and @lesson.next.  In the model I did this:

```
def next
  self.number + 1
end 

def previous
  self.number - 1
end
```

But alas, I get @instance nil error again.

Comment: Weirdly, if I pass a parameter from the view that contains anything, the instance variable's value is lost and returns nil. So, in my view I need to pass along the instance variable but once I accept that value as a parameter, it gets lost. Can anyone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: Your issue is that you're calling `link_to "Next", 12` (assuming current_lesson.number is 11) and rails doesn't know what to do with that. What should it do?

Comment: Ok. My current URL is say lessons/2 I want next to get to lessons/3 and previous lessons/1. It is just a way to say go to the next numbered lesson.

Answer (score 0):

self.next & self.previous return integer instead of Lesson. Make them return next and previous Lesson objects and it should work. I.e

```
    Lesson.find_by_number(self.number-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function

```
def self.next
  current_lesson = Lesson.find(@lesson.id)
  next_lesson = current_lesson.number + 1
end
```

you will return a Fixnum instead of a Lesson object.

If you want to return a Lesson with an id 1 higher you are probably better off doing something  like:

```
def next
  Lesson.find(self.number + 1)
end
```

Comment: That makes sense. But when I try to reload it says 'Couldn't find Lesson with 'id'=1'.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting the error is that `Lesson.next` and `Lesson.previous` return integers and not lesson objects. If you wanted to continue using the `next` and `previous` class methods, you could make the following change in your view

```
<p><%= link_to 'Previous', lesson_path(Lesson.previous(@lesson)) %></p>
<p><%= link_to 'Next', lesson_path(Lesson.next(@lesson)) %></p>
```